# Ayuda con login en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, programación-móvil

Perdón por lo principiante, pero estoy hace poco introduciéndome en este mundo de la programación, lo que pasa es que quiero redireccionar el activity login a otro activity pero nose como, al momento de loguearme correctamente, se valida el usuario pero no se redirecciona hacia otro activity, ¿Porque será?

Lo que yo busco principalmente es que después de mandar el mensaje de que el usuario se logueó correctamente, me mande directo hacia otro activity.

Login.java:

```
    package com.example.asus.crudaplicacion;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1,e2;
    Button b1,b2;
    DatabaseHelper db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loguear);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.segunda);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email=e1.getText().toString();
                String password=e2.getText().toString();
                Boolean Chkemailpass=db.emailpassword(email,password);
                if(Chkemailpass==true)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha iniciado sesión correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email o contraseña incorrectos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });


    }
}
```

activity_login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usuario"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Escriba su email..."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.21"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Escriba su password..."
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.21"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usuario" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loguear"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Iniciar sesión"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en ningún sitio le indicas que tiene que pasar a la siguiente actividad, para ello tienes que utilizar un Intent.

Aquí tienes un guión para ver todo en detalle: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419

Según tu código, quedaría así:

```
package com.example.asus.crudaplicacion;

import android.content.Intent;//Esta es la librería para poder utilizar el intent 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1,e2;
    Button b1,b2;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usuario);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loguear);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.segunda);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email=e1.getText().toString();
                String password=e2.getText().toString();
                Boolean Chkemailpass=db.emailpassword(email,password);
                if(Chkemailpass==true){ //Añadimos llaves ya que va a haber más de una línea de código
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha iniciado sesión correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActividad.class);  //Creamos el intent y le indicamos desde donde vamos (this) y a donde vamos (OtraActividad.class)
                    startActivity(intent);  //Abrimos la otra actividad
                }else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email o contraseña incorrectos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            String email=e1.getText().toString();
            String password=e2.getText().toString();
            Boolean Chkemailpass=db.emailpassword(email,password);
            if(Chkemailpass==true)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha iniciado sesión correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NOMBRE DE TU CLASE ACTIVITY.class);
            startActivity(intent);

```
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email o contraseña incorrectos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Unicamente ingresa esta linea de código para que te envíe a el segundo activity
Debes agregar la librería de el Intent con las teclas alt-enter o direcamente importar import android.content.Intent;
Espero me haya explicado, te sirva y sea de utilidad.

Comment: Pero en que parte debo ponerlo? Debajo del mensaje que el usuario se logueó correctamente?

Comment: El código que has puesto abriría siempre la segunda actividad, tiene que ir dentro del if.

Comment: Disculpa si es después de el mensaje que tienes  como "Ha iniciado sesión correctamente"

Comment: Es correcto tu comentario, para ello con el if que tienes, debes validar el usuario y contraseña. una vez validado mandara al activity que esta apuntando.

Comment: Es por las llaves creo, mira mi respuesta, es básicamente igual pero creo que he cuadrado las llaves

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfectamente!!

Comment: es correcto lo que menciona Pablo Simón.
agrega las llaves tanto al if como al else.